# Jetpack Compose LazyColum state not changing when changes are made inside of containing objects

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

[image]

Below is a simple Cart Implementation where the value of qty should increase by 1 if a list item is clicked...

But somehow values in the ViewModel are changing, but not reflected in UI ( not recomposing with new qty value)

I think problem lies in this part :
`LazyColumn {items(cartInfo.value!!.cartItems){...}`

as `cartItems` is not directly a state value that's why not triggering the recomposition of the LazyColumn UI.

But cant solve this problem as `mutableStateOf<CartInfo?>` is fixed and I don't want a separate state for `MutableList<CartItem>`

```kotlin
data class User(var id: String, var name: String)
data class Product(var id: String, var name: String)
data class CartItem(var product: Product, var qty: Int)
data class CartInfo(val userid: String, val cartItems: MutableList<CartItem>)

val user = User("1", "A")
val item1 = CartItem(Product("1", "iPhone"), 1)
val item2 = CartItem(Product("2", "Xbox"), 1)
val cart = CartInfo(user.id, mutableListOf(item1, item2))

class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _cartInfo = mutableStateOf<CartInfo?>(null)
    val cartInfo: State<CartInfo?> = _cartInfo

    init {
        _cartInfo.value = cart
    }

    fun increaseQty(product: Product, user: User) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            var cartInfo = cartInfo.value

            if (user.id == cartInfo?.userid) {
                var cartItems = cartInfo.cartItems.map {
                    if (it.product.id == product.id) {
                        it.qty += 1
                        it
                    } else
                        it
                }
                _cartInfo.value = cartInfo.copy(cartItems = cartItems as MutableList<CartItem>)
            }
//            Log.d("debug", "viewmodel: ${cartInfo?.cartItems.toString()}")
        }
    }

}


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val viewModel by viewModels<MainViewModel>()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    val cartInfo = viewModel.cartInfo
                    Log.d("debug", cartInfo.toString())

                    LazyColumn {
                        items(cartInfo.value!!.cartItems) {
                            Card(modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .padding(5.dp)
                                .clickable {
                                    viewModel.increaseQty(it.product, user)
                                }) {
                                Row() {
                                    Text(
                                        text = "${it.product.name}",
                                        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f).padding(10.dp)
                                    )
                                    Text(
                                        text = "qty: ${it.qty}"
                                    )
                                }

                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line `_cartInfo.value = cartInfo` you set the same object in your `_cartInfo`.

Mutable state cannot check if the state of your internal object has changed, it can only check if it is the same object or not.

You can make your `CartInfo` a data class which allows you to easily create a new object with `copy`. Make sure you do not use any `var` or modifiable collections such as `MutableList` to reduce the chance of error. Check out [Why is immutability important in functional programming?](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-immutability-important-in-functional-programming).

```kotlin
data class CartInfo(val id: String, val cartItems: List<Item>)

// usage
_cartInfo.value = cartInfo.copy(cartItems = cartItems)
```

Comment: Tried already :  `_cartInfo.value = cartInfo.copy(cartItems = cartItems as MutableList<CartItem>)`  still doesn't work.......but completely changing the cartitems object works, for example:  ` _cartInfo.value = cartInfo.copy(cartItems = mutableListOf(item1, item2, item1))``

Comment: the problem was this part  `it.qty += 1`.....now it is solved. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Creating new `CartItem` with `CartItem(it.product, qty = it.qty + 1)` solved the problem:

```kotlin
fun increaseQty(product: Product, user: User) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            var cartInfo = cartInfo.value

            if (user.id == cartInfo?.userid) {
                var cartItems = cartInfo.cartItems.map {
                    if (it.product.id == product.id) {
//                        old:
//                        it.qty += 1
//                        it
//                       changes made:
                        CartItem(it.product, qty = it.qty + 1)
                    } else
                        it
                }
                _cartInfo.value = cartInfo.copy(cartItems = cartItems as MutableList<CartItem>)
            }
        }
}
```